# export data to excel not working in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

export data and TableTools not working for me, after adding this line between head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../components/dataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../components/dataTables/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../components/dataTables/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
```

and change table id prop in this:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
   "sDom": '<"clear">lfrtipT'
});
```

i can see tableTools buttons on the table but, thay are not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First use the jquery datable js 1.9 (please check the below link where you can download this js)
and second use the code like below to view datatable

```
$('#example').dataTable({
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"oTableTools": {
"aButtons": [
{
'sExtends':'csv',
"sFileName": "subscribers_"+GetTodayDate()+".csv",
'mColumns':[0,1]
},
{
'sExtends':'pdf',
"sFileName": "subscribers_"+GetTodayDate()+".pdf",
'mColumns':[0,1] 
},
]
},
"sDom": '<"H"Tlfr>tip<"F">',
"aoColumns":
[
{ "bSearchable": false },
null,
{ "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
]
});
```

please remember main code for export to excel is as below
which is added in the above code

```
"oTableTools": {
"aButtons": [
{
'sExtends':'csv',
"sFileName": "subscribers.csv",
'mColumns':[0,1]
},
{
'sExtends':'pdf',
"sFileName": "subscribers.pdf",
'mColumns':[0,1] 
},
]
},
"sDom": '<"H"Tlfr>tip<"F">',
```

and then download the "media" folder from this link and paste into the folder where you datagrid show

[NOTE : please extract and paste the "media" folder in the accurate path on which page your datatable is display .]

Comment: Please note here are  Required files 
1)datatable/media/css/demo_table_jui.css
2)datatable/media/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css
3)datatable/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css
4)datatable/media/js/1.9/jquery.dataTables.js
5)datatable/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js
6)datatable/media/js/TableTools.js

Answer (score 1):

For that you will need a file:

1. copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf

You will get it here: [Google Datatable SWF](http://code.google.com/p/alageospatialportal/source/browse/trunk/actions/src/main/webapp/includes/dashboard/datatables/swf/)
Try following code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "sDom": '<"clear">lfrtipT',
        "oTableTools": {
              "sSwfPath" : "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    });
});
```

Where set `sSwfPath` value to absolute path to the `copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` file.

---

Check this link for more info: [TableTools example - setting SWF path](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf_path.html)