# Initialize DataTables TableTools through DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, tabletools

I'm trying to follow [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation) supposedly simple initialization process for `DataTables` plugin `TableTools`. As far as I can tell, I'm simply supposed to specify the `tableTools` parameter, within which I follow the same process to initialize other `TableTools` options. However, I'm getting literally nothing using the code below.

Is there anyone familiar with the plugin that can help?

**jQuery**

```
$('#ReportTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": array,
    "aoColumns": headers,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Filter results:"
    },
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "aButtons": [ "copy", "print" ]
    }
});
```

**Results**

I just get the `DataTable`, not `TableTools` button menu.

[image]

Comment: Refered to this post for a solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970883/export-data-to-excel-not-working-in-datatables

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I solved it by changing

```
"dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',"
```

to

```
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'"
```

(change dom to sDom). No idea why, but it worked.